# Mapping the columns of user uploaded excel files

Tags: excel, csv, user-interface, modeling

I have a trained model that I want to expose via a webapp to make new predictions based on user uploaded files.

I need the columns of the user's uploaded file (excel, csv) to conform to a set of assumptions/expectations.

I was imagining a sort of wizard that asks the user questions like: "Thanks for uploading your file, now ..."

1. What is the name of the column for account balance?
2. What is the name of the column for date the account was opened?

This workflow of "User uploads data" -> "Collect additional user input" -> "Do something" seems common enough.

I found this thing:

- https://github.com/wq/django-data-wizard
- and google maps: http://www.cartagram.com/5648/from-excel-to-google-maps/
- and this isn't bad either: https://batchgeo.com/

Any other thoughts on how to keep this relatively painless and maximize user experience?

Comment: don't suppose you could just provide a template to the user and require that template in order to upload?

Comment: @KeithAymar honestly that's probably the best thing to do as a first pass

Comment: Yes, I think so too.  Get the code to process the data first.  Then add a validation process to import the data.  You may be able to be a little flexible and tell the user that the column data requires that the headers have certain names regardless of position.  Like "Last Name" header assumes a Last Name.  Its very difficult to depend on the user to do the right thing in these situations.  You will have to validate all the data.  I would do this in an initial pass before actually processing anything.